# I have many separate installs for magento can I merge them together?

Tags: magento

I've just started a new job and we have several installs of magneto all of different versions!

Now really it seems to me that we need to firstly upgrade them all and then get them all under one installation of magneto and using one database.

What is the best way (in general terms) of doing this.
Is it even possible or is my best bet to make the sites again under one installation and import the products into it.

There is some talk by a fellow developer that having them under different installs helps with performance. Is this true?

Once we have them all under one install things like stock control and orders as well as putting products on multiple site should also be very straightforward - correct?

We are talking quite a few stores say around 15ish and quite a few products around I would say 4000 maybe more.

Answer (score 8):

My first suggestion is to consider the reasons, why you need all Magento instances to be moved under one installation. The reasons are not clear from your question. So the best developer's advice is "Does it work? Then don't touch it" :)

If there are no specific reasons, then you'd better leave it as is. All reorganization processes (upgrading, infrastructure configuration, access setup, etc.) for a software system are hard, costly, consume time, error-prone, usually have no much value from business point of view and are a little boring. This is not a Magento-specific thing, it is just general characteristic for any software.

Also note, that it is a holiday season. So it is better not to do anything with e-commerce stores until the middle of January.

If you see value in a reorganization of your Magento stores, then the best way to do it is to go gradually - step by step, store by store:

1. Take your most complex store. Prepare everything you need for the further steps - i.e. get ready the tools, write automatic scripts, go through the process with its copy at some testing server.  Write set of functional tests
   to cover it with at least smoke-tests. You'll have to repeat
   such light checks many times to be sure, that the store appears to be
   working. The automatic tests will save much time. Thus all these preparations will decrease your downtime.
2. Close public access to the store.
3. Upgrade store to the Magento version, you need. Move it to the new infrastructure.
4. Verify all the user scenarios manually and with automatic tests. Fix the issues, if any.
5. Open public access to the store. Monitor logs, load reports at the server machines. Fix issues, if any.
6. Take next store (let's call it NextStore). Make its copy at a sandbox server.
7. Make copy of your already converted store (let's call it ConvertedStore) at a sandbox server.
8. Export all the data from copy of NextStore and import it to the copy of ConvertedStore. You can use Magento Dataflow or Import/Export modules to do that. Not all data can be
   imported/exported with those modules - just Catalog, Orders, Customers. You will need
   to develop custom scripts to import/export other entities, if you need them.
9. Verify result manually and with automatic tests and manually. Write automatic scripts, that fix found issues. You will need those scripts later during the real converting process.
10. Close NextStore.
11. Move it to the new infrastructure, by engaging the already prepared procedures and scripts. You will need to consider, whether to close ConvertedStore during the converting process. It depends on your feeling, whether it is ok to have it opened or not. For safety reasons it is better to close it.
12. Verify, that everything works fine. Monitor logs, reports.
13. Fix issues, if any.
14. Proceed with the rest of your stores.

That is my (totally personal) view on the procedures.

> There is some talk by a fellow developer that having them under
>   different installs helps with performance. Is this true?

Yes, your friend is right. Separating Magento (actually, anything in this world) into smaller instances makes it lighter to be handled. The performance difference is very small (for your instance of 4000 products), but it is inevitable. Consider, that after combining the instances (suppose, there are ten of them with 400 products each) you'll be handling data for 10x more customers, reports, products, stores, etc. Therefore any search will have to go through ten times more products, in order to return data. Of course, it doesn't matter, if the search takes 0.00001 second, because 0.0001s for combined instance is ok as well. But some things, like sorting or matching sets, grow non-linearly. But, as said before, for 4000 products you won't see big difference.

> Once we have them all under one install things like stock control and
>   orders as well as putting products on multiple site should also be
>   very straightforward - correct?

You're right - after combining the stores together, handling orders, stock, customers will be much more simpler and straightforward process.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to consider is what problem you're solving by having all these sites on one Magento "instance". What's more important to your business/team: having these sites share product and inventory or having the flexibility of independently modifying these sites? Any downtime or impacts to availability may affect all sites.

Further questions/areas of investigation:
   How much does the product hierarchy (categories and attributes) differ?
   Is pricing the same across each site or different? 
   Are any of these sites multi-regional and how is pricing handled for each region?

It's certainly possible to run multiple sites on one Magento instances, even if there are some rough edges within the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no way to export all entities in Magento, there's no functionality to merge stores. You'd have to write custom code - it would have to take all the records from the old store, assign them new IDs while preserving referential integrity & insert them into the new store (this is what the "product import" does, but they don't have it for categories, orders, customers, etc.).

The amount of code you'd be writing to do that would take almost longer than just starting over in my opinion. You'd basically be writing the missing functionality for Magento. If it were easy they would have it done it already.

However splitting two stores apart is very easy, since you don't have to worry about reassigning unique identifiers in the DB.